# How do I Delete Code in .R java file?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

When I was naming one of my activities in Android Studio, I accidentally clicked the "\" key and I've deleted that activity but now when I run the project it says I have an error in my .R java file..

I tried to delete the error which will fix my problem, but whenever I delete the line of code it just regenerates it when I run it again...

I've already tried; deleting the line, cleaning my project, and rebuilding my project. None have worked.

The line of code I need to delete is:

`public static final int title_activity_song_one_hundred_nine\=0x7f0c0054;`

How do I go about deleting this line of code for good? Thanks.

Comment: Please pay attention to the fact that the `r` tag is for R software.

Comment: Delete the code that generates that line. Looks like a strings.xml variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean your project by
**Build > Clean Project / Rebuild Project**. this should re-compiles your R file in android studio.

If still not work, you must have errors in your resource files. Check your xml files such as layout, string, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! The line of code was in the strings layout. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Close your app in an `Android Studio/Eclipse`.Go to your workspace where you have the project.Open that **`R.jave`** file in notepad and remove the `"/"` symbol then save it.

Now open it in `Android Studio/Eclipse IDE`. Your error may fix.